# MYSQL : Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value, while inserting a csv file

Tags: mysql, sql

i get the following error while inserting a csv file with date columns.

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '17-06-2018' for column 'date_of_arrival' at row 1
```

Below is the code that I use to insert into table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\Data.csv'
INTO TABLE assign
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
SET date_of_arrival = STR_TO_DATE(@date_of_arrival, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

In the csv file the dates are in the format..

```
date_of_arrival
17-06-2018
24-06-2018
.
.
```

I have given the correct formatting.

Comment: It could be that the `date_of_arrival` column is of type `DATE`, and that requires the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. You're using 'DD-MM-YYYY'.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes its in ```DATE``` type. Do you mean I have to change it at csv level to YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question better. You're already trying to convert the format with `STR_TO_DATE()`. I think you have to define where `@date_of_arrival` comes from. See [Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing). The way I explain the error is that your conversion didn't work, because of this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I re-created the table with that column type as ```VARCHAR```. I then removed the ```@``` in the ```SET``` command. The command worked and table gets populated. However in the table settings UI, I can still see the column type as VARCHAR. It was supposed to be changed as ```DATE``` while I do this ```STR_TO_DATE```  operation right ?

Comment: Not sure I read your last comment right but set does not change datatype nor does str_to_date which simply converts a string to a valid mysql date format..